# Traer nombre de mis archivos de una carpeta

Tags: php, codeigniter

tengo un problema, intento traer los nombres de los archivo que tengo en una carpeta pero no que queda, tengo el siguiente código y jala pero estoy accediendo a **‘C:’** pero lo que necesito es que quiero traer los archivos que tengo en mis assets que vendría siendo mi **base_url** para después acceder a **assets** y cuando lo pongo me marca error de ruta.

```
$carpeta = 'c:\MAMP';
    if(is_dir($carpeta)){
      if($dir = opendir($carpeta)){
          while(($archivo = readdir($dir)) !== false){
              if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess'){
                  echo '<li><a target="_blank" href="'.$carpeta.'/'.$archivo.'">'.$archivo.'</a></li>';
              }
          }
          closedir($dir);
      }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te da?

Comment: cuando cambio c:\MAMP por mi ruta que es ../../ no es que me marque error, si no que no me trae nada

Comment: perdon es ../../assets/

Comment: Y si solo dejas "./assets/"

Comment: Gracias, ya quedo

Comment: @Javierfr nos viene genial si nos compartes la solución, muchas gracias :)

Comment: solo tengo una duda

Comment: la verdad no se que estan haciendo algunas partes del cofigo, podrian ayudarme a explicar que se hace en cada linea de codigo